# Arduino google sheet integration

Tags: google-sheets, arduino, project

I'm doing a project with Arduino, I'm trying to post variable's data into google sheet integration but the code doesn't work.

I tried to correct it, but it doesn't post anyway....this is the code.

The error was

> ss.sheet.getSheetByName it's not a function

I took the code from Arduino IoT Cloud Google sheet Integration

```
function myFunction() {
        // get sheet named RawData
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dati");

        var MAX_ROWS = 1440;     // max number of data rows to display
        // 3600s / cloud_int(30s) * num_ore(12h)
        var HEADER_ROW = 1;     // row index of header
        var TIMESTAMP_COL = 1;  // column index of the timestamp column

        function doPost(e) {  
          var cloudData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); // this is a json object containing all info coming from IoT Cloud
          //var webhook_id = cloudData.webhook_id; // really not using these three
          //var device_id = cloudData.device_id;
          //var thing_id = cloudData.thing_id;
          var values = cloudData.values; // this is an array of json objects
          
          // store names and values from the values array
          // just for simplicity
          var incLength = values.length;
          var incNames = [];
          var incValues = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < incLength; i++) {
            incNames[i] = values[i].name;
            incValues[i] = values[i].value;
          }
          
          // read timestamp of incoming message
          var timestamp = values[0].updated_at;          // format: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.mmmZ
          var date = new Date(Date.parse(timestamp)); 
          
          /*
          This if statement is due to the fact that duplicate messages arrive from the cloud!
          If that occurs, the timestamp is not read correctly and date variable gets compromised.
          Hence, execute the rest of the script if the year of the date is well defined and it is greater
          then 2018 (or any other year before)
          */
          if (date.getYear() > 2018) {
          
            // discard all messages that arrive 'late'
            if (sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW+1, 1).getValue() != '') { // for the first time app is run
              var now = new Date(); // now
              var COMM_TIME = 5; // rough overestimate of communication time between cloud and app
              if (now.getTime() - date.getTime() > COMM_TIME * 1000) {
                return;
              }
            }
            
            // this section write property names 
            sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW, 1).setValue('timestamp');
            for (var i = 0; i < incLength; i++) {
              var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn(); // at the very beginning this should return 1 // second cycle -> it is 2
              if (lastCol == 1) {
                sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW, lastCol + 1).setValue(incNames[i]);
              } else {
                // check if the name is already in header
                var found = 0;
                for (var col = 2; col <= lastCol; col++) {
                  if (sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW, col).getValue() == incNames[i]) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                if (found == 0) {
                  sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW, lastCol+1).setValue(incNames[i]);
                }
              }
            }
            
            // redefine last column and last row since new names could have been added
            var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
            var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
            
            // delete last row to maintain constant the total number of rows
            if (lastRow > MAX_ROWS + HEADER_ROW - 1) { 
              sheet.deleteRow(lastRow);
            }
            
            // insert new row after deleting the last one
            sheet.insertRowAfter(HEADER_ROW);
            
            // reset style of the new row, otherwise it will inherit the style of the header row
            var range = sheet.getRange('A2:Z2');
            //range.setBackground('#ffffff');
            range.setFontColor('#000000');
            range.setFontSize(10);
            range.setFontWeight('normal');
            
            // write the timestamp
            sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW+1, TIMESTAMP_COL).setValue(date).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            
            // write values in the respective columns
            for (var col = 1+TIMESTAMP_COL; col <= lastCol; col++) {
              // first copy previous values
              // this is to avoid empty cells if not all properties are updated at the same time
              sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW+1, col).setValue(sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW+2, col).getValue());
              for (var i = 0; i < incLength; i++) {
                var currentName = sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW, col).getValue();
                if (currentName == incNames[i]) {
                  // turn boolean values into 0/1, otherwise google sheets interprets them as labels in the graph
                  if (incValues[i] == true) {
                    incValues[i] = 1;
                  } else if (incValues[i] == false) {
                    incValues[i] = 0;
                  }
                  sheet.getRange(HEADER_ROW+1, col).setValue(incValues[i]);
                } 
              }
            }  
          
          } // end if (date.getYear() > 2018)
        }  
}
```

Comment: In your script, `function doPost(e) {,,,}` is put in the function of `myFunction`. In this case, how do you execute the function of `myFunction` and `doPost`? And, where is the line of the error of `ss.sheet.getSheetByName it's not a function` in your script?

Comment: Idk how to program javascript i only copied the arduino code from this https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Arduino_Genuino/arduino-iot-cloud-google-sheets-integration-71b6bc and i noticed that the first and the second line showed the error

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: Where are you running this code from?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push data directly to the Google sheet on the cloud but it's URL uses https for security reasons. The encryption for https is rather complex and SSL crypto is required. Arduino hardware is normally not fast enough to do SSL. You need more powerful hardware like Raspberry Pi to write directly to the Google Cloud.

However, you can use PushingBox, a cloud that can send notifications based on API calls, to do the hard work for you if you insist on using Arduino ( any variant) in your IOT project. Here you send your data to Pushingbox, it uses http URL, and it will in turn the data to Google sheet.

Comment: This seems unlikely as they're either 1) using an Arduino that _does_ connect directly to a network 2) connecting via some connected computer (rather than from the microcontroller itself) .. the link they posted in a comment makes 1 seem more likely, and refers to a much more powerful, Arduino-compatible device with a 32-bit ARM chip!